# GPS signal strength over locations

Tags: geospatial, data

Is there any data with GPS signal strength information? I'm trying to understand GPS wrt locations and some just in general have better signal than rest. Is there any data suggestive of this, which says like at this latitude and longitude, GPS in not that great? Like the satellites don't have a great reach, like at high elevations and areas like that.